# SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development - .htaccess interacting with Zend Framework?

Tags: apache, zend-framework

I have the following on my htaccess.

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
```

When I pass this file to prodution, I will change it to:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production
```

This

> development

and

> production

are set on Zend Framework *application.ini* correct ?

**How does Zend and Apache communicate here? How does Zend knows about that htaccess instruction?**

Thanks.

Comment: Nice idea, that! Never seen this before.

Comment: Oh well, credits go to the book author that I'm reading. :) W.J. Gilmore. But this "how" was omitted. :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**`SetEnv`**, used in Apache's configuration (be it a .htaccess file, or a VirtualHost), defines an environment variable.

From PHP, you can read environment variables either :

- using the [**`getenv()`**](https://www.php.net/getenv) function.
- Or in the [**`$_SERVER`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) or **[`$_ENV`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php)** superglobal variables

Taking a look at the given `index.php` in [Zend Frameworks QuickStart][4], you'll see it uses that environment variable the define the PHP constant called `APPLICATION_ENV` :

```
// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV',
              (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV')
                                         : 'production'));
```

And that constant is later used to initialize the application :

```
// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
```

Comment: `APPLICATION_ENV` is used to load the correct section of your configuration file *(or some section of PHP code)* -- in which you enable *(or not)* the displaying of errors.

Answer (score 9):

The flow of communication, as you call it, is the followoing:

If you use

> SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production

in your .htaccess, the environment you set there, will be used. Why?

The following piece of code from your index.php doesn't define the constant, if it has been defined already, which is the case, if you use SetEnv in your .htaccess.

```
// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV',
              (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV')
                                         : 'production'));
```

If your .htaccess doesn't define the constant, the value provided in the index.php will be used. If I were you, I would still keep it in sync. Because you may make mistakes like forgetting to set AllowOverride for your vhost which would result in a situation where the environment is set by the index.php even though the .htaccess is present.

Comment: I will take that into consideration, but it will not be easy doing. I'm trying to automate the process using capistrano. At this moment, I've created a task there, that will replace htaccessA by htaccessB that is on a "production" folder. The htaccess files are not changeable so often as our index.php file, so I could rely on this...

Comment: In general I find it a good idea to define the environment in the .htaccess, just make sure, the default environment in the index.php is the most secure one (which would be production) just in case there is a problem with .htaccess. Maybe you could also rewrite the index.php in a way that the application throws an error, if the environment hasn't been set by the .htaccess.